# What is allowed in a <a> tag

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I've looked in W3C specs and couldn't find what is allowed in a `<a>` tag. I'm asking this because I got a strange behavior while developing a svelte app. In dev mode, the app was able to wrap a `<th>` inside a `<a>` like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Services</th>
            <a href="#details"><th>Details*</th></a>
            <th>Coût</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I got the expected result, a clickable th with a bookmark link to another section in the page.

But when I deployed the production code, svelte didn't wrap the `<th>` inside a `<a>`. I also did some tests in [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/scharpentier0/pen/WNrGbym) *(enable and siable the Javascript comment to see the difference)* and was surprised to learn that a `<th>` can't be wrapped with an `<a>` natively but can be forced using Javascript.

Is there a place where I could find a list of the elements allowed within an `<a>` tag as I always though anything could be wrapped with one.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not about the content of the `a`; the invalid part is having an `a` in a `tr`, whose only valid content is `td` and `th`. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#Technical_summary.

Comment: @SamualCharpentier Have you tried just swapping the element order? So...`<th><a...`

Comment: While it's not your issue here, take a look at MDN's link in the [Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Properties) section for `<a>`, and look at "Permitted content." Click through a few of those links and do some reading to answer the question in your last sentence.

Comment: Yes swapping the elements works but only the text is clickable, not the shape. Unless I made the `<a>` `display:block` which is an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-th-element the `th` element can only be used inside a `tr` element.